# Upgrading Laptop SSD to larger size, can't initialize drive

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, ssd, upgrade, usb-c

MSI Dominator GT62VR laptop. Came with M.2 128gb SSD (THNSNJ128G8NY) for the OS volume (another TB for files, games etc), want to upgrade the OS volume to the 256GB version (THNSNJ256G8NY). I bought the drive, and an external enclosure for it. My plan was to clone the existing drive then just swap them out.

BUT, when I hooked the drive into the enclosure and plugged it in (USB C), the computer recognizes it as a 'Removable drive' and in disk management there is no option to initialize it or create a new volume or anything.

How can I make it recognize the drive as a real drive and not a USB drive? Is it the enclosure doing this? The enclosure that I have is 'Rosewill RHUB-20001 USB C to M.2 NVMe'. Am I out of luck here?

Comment: You can try installing the new M.2 and then just booting from a Windows installation media which you put on a USB drive. Then you'd have a fresh install of Windows on your new computer, and you can click and drag your files from the old drive onto your new one. This will require you reinstall some applications, but you won't really be able to clone unless you have 2 M.2 slots in a PC available. This hinges on the idea that Windows install media can initialize your drive, so if you try this be sure you report back here if it works.

Comment: I'm really hoping I don't have to go this route. I would like to do a clone if possible. Trying a few other softwares to see if I can get that drive initialized first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>This is due to the stupid way Windows threats USB storage media. It usually thinks everything is a USB stick and limits what you can do with it.</strike>

You need 3rd party software for the cloning. Windows doesn't include clone-tools suitable for this.
Your clone software should be able to make a 1 on 1 clone anyway (and extend the C: drive on the new disk afterwards), because it makes the clone using low-level disk-access which bypasses the normal Windows logic.

P.S.
Don't wipe the old disk before you are sure you can boot the new M.2 after cloning. I have seen it happen that something goes wrong and you need to make a new clone attempt (possibly with adjusted settings).

EDIT

I just checked the specifications on the laptop, M.2 SSD and the enclosure.

Your SSD is a M.2 SATA SSD, but your enclosure ONLY supports M.2 NVMe SSD's.

M.2 slots can be SSD, NVMe or BOTH and the same goes for M.2 devices. Both sides need to support the same standard.
So this will never work. The SSD and the enclosure are incompatible.

Your laptop only accepts the M.2 SATA version so your SSD itself is the correct type for the laptop.

Comment: I tried using macrium reflect, it doesn't even recognize the drive at all. I can't select it as a destination for a clone.

Comment: @BuddyWagner CloneZilla or EaseUS Partition Master (Free Edition) should both be able to do it.

Comment: I tried EaseUS, it does not recognize the drive either. I'll try CloneZilla.

Comment: Same result with CloneZilla, I'm starting to think the enclosure that I have is causing issues, or it could be a problem with the USB C port. Or maybe there is an updated BIOS with a setting I need to get USB C port to be recognized as a hard drive.

Comment: @BuddyWagner I just checked the specs on the SSD and the enclosure. Your SSD is a M.2 SATA SSD, the enclosure ONLY supports M.2 NVMe SSD's. This will never work. And your laptop only accepts the SATA version, so you need another enclosure. The SSD itself is the correct type

Comment: This makes sense. I wasn't totally confident in that purchase originally as the whole M.2 scene is new to me. My initial suspicion was that the enclosure was the problem. To confirm before I buy a new one, would this one work:

https://www.newegg.com/wavlink-237c-enclosure/p/0VN-0069-00016

Comment: @Buddy Yes, that one should work.

Comment: I ordered that one, we'll see if that fixes it. If so I'll mark this as the answer.

Comment: That was the issue, got it all sorted out now and hard disk upgraded.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Clonezilla https://clonezilla.org/ that

1. put Clonezilla on a USB flash drive: https://clonezilla.org/liveusb.php so that you'll be able to boot from drive
2. Connect 256GB to your USB
3. Reboot & enter bios settings where you enable boot from a flash drive that you created with Clonezilla
4. As your computer boot into Clonezilla you can clone partitions from original M.2 SSD to your new 256GB drive
5. Swap M.2 disks and (change back boot sequence in BIOS) boot computer  into your OS, where you'll be able to resize partition

However: You might have some problems if your computer uses EFI partitions, but the procedure works. You just have to play around.

About your question: USB drive is a real drive connected with USB. That is OK! If the partitions are ok, it will act as a real drive after you swap disks.

Comment: Having the same issues with CloneZilla, I was able to boot from USB into CloneZilla but once in there, it doesn't recognize the drive at all. I wonder if this is because I'm going in through USB C? I did have to change my BIOS settings to get it to boot, there was a PNY 2.0 setting set to AUTO, I had to set it to HARD DISK. Changing this setting had no effect on the drive connected to USB C though.

Comment: Do you see disk in BIOS?

Comment: No, I don't. The only place that it shows up is in windows as a removable drive, but I can't format it or initialize it or anything. All options are greyed out or otherwise unavailable.

Comment: I agree with Tony "Not compatible with M.2 SATA SSDs". You have to get new enclosure.